# active state on li on page init

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this chunk of code which outputs a list of pages within the current scope of a given section. I am trying to get the li (section title) of the current active page to display an active state when on that given page. I haven't been able to find an answer to this and I am new to Angular2. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <ul class="child-ul-nav" *ngIf="page.layout === 'page' && page.sections">
    <li class="child-li-nav" *ngFor="let section of page.sections">
      {{section.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a directive called RouterLinkActive: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: @Bluesight doesn't seem that this list is using the router.

Comment: You should provide more information (for instance the version of Angular and/or if you're using router or not, ....).
Would be useful also provide a minimal working example (for instance in stackblitz or plunkr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added (section.id === page.id) to the [class.active]

```
 <ul class="child-ul-nav" *ngIf="parentPage && parentPage.layout === 'page' && parentPage.sections">
      <li class="child-li-nav" *ngFor="let section of parentPage.sections">
        <span [class.active]="section.id === page.id">{{section.title}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this by inserting a property 'URL' in each object of parentPage.sections array which corresponds to the Url the page a goes after clicking the li i.e

parentPage.sections = [{
'title': 'sample title1',
'url': '/url/suburl1',
....
},{
'title': 'sample title2',
'url': '/url/suburl2',
....
}];

you will get the URLs from routes property in angular-router you have configured in app.module.ts or lazyLoaded.module.ts if you have done lazy loading

next thing you will get the current URL from 'Router' class, assigning the current URL to the local variable of the component i.e


**In .ts**

constructor(public router: Router){
this.currentUrl = router.url;
}

**In .html**

<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <ul class="child-ul-nav" *ngIf="page.layout === 'page' && page.sections">
    <li class="child-li-nav" [ngClass]="currentUrl === section.url ?'active-li':''" *ngFor="let section of page.sections">
      {{section.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```